# Running an Eclipse Builder before program launch

Tags: eclipse, plugins, build

I'm trying to write an Eclipse plug-in which takes part in the build process. However, I'd like my Builder to execute only before the user tries to launch his program, and not during normal compilation.

As an example, I noticed that part of the Android SDK builder is executing during compilation, but other parts only before program launch (the APK builder), and I'm trying to do the same.

I've extended IncrementalProjectBuilder, and my build() method gets called during incremental and full builds, but I couldn't find a way to make it run only before the user tries to launch the program (run or debug).
Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Ariel

Comment: At a guess the Android code is using its own launch configuration code which can do this (`ILaunchConfiguration` and associated interfaces).

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right @greg-449. I found that the Android SDK is registering the APK Builder as a builder in Eclipse for the purpose of running it during normal builds only if you unselect "Skip packaging and dexing..." from the Android build preferences page. Otherwise I guess they're just invoking it directly when their launch configuration code runs.